# Rows to columns when data sometimes is missing

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Transform data from rows to columns. I've got two `ID` rows, and one text `VARCHAR2` type row. But one of the `ID` rows not always the same. Sometime missing the data.

I tried with `PIVOT` and `GROUP BY` until now this gave me only errors.

```sql
SELECT prj_id, udn_id, txt_value
FROM TBL
GROUP BY tbl.prj_id;
```

I would like transform this:
(The empty line is only for the better visibility)

```
PRJ_ID  UDN_ID  TXT_ VALUE
8344    82      13/10/2009
8344    64      E S
8344    178     End

8364    82      12/10/2009
8364    64      A M
8364    89      M
8364    178     Internal

8335    82      05/10/2009
8335    64      E S
8335    89      N
8335    178     End

8377    82      13/10/2009
8377    64      Z D
8377    89      N;M
8377    178     Internal
```

to this:

```
        82          64      89      178         
8344    13/10/2009  E S     N/A     End
8364    12/10/2009  A M     M       Internal
8335    05/10/2009  E S     N       End
8377    13/10/2009  Z D     N;M     Internal
```

Any idea how can solve this with SQL?

Comment: The start table have 3 million lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *oldfashioned* way (prior to `PIVOT`) was to aggregate value using `DECODE` (or `CASE`, for better readability). Here's an example (lines 16 onwards are what you're looking for):

```
SQL> with tbl (prj_id, udn_id, txt_value) as
  2    (select 8344, 82, '13/10/2009' from dual union all
  3     select 8344, 64, 'E S'        from dual union all
  4     select 8344, 178, 'End'       from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 8364, 82, '12/10/2009' from dual union all
  7     select 8364, 64, 'A M'        from dual union all
  8     select 8364, 89, 'M'          from dual union all
  9     select 8364, 178, 'Internal'  from dual union all
 10     --
 11     select 8335, 82, '05/10/2009' from dual union all
 12     select 8335, 64, 'E S'        from dual union all
 13     select 8335, 89, 'N'          from dual union all
 14     select 8335, 178, 'End'       from dual
 15    )
 16  select prj_id,
 17         max(case when udn_id =  82 then txt_value end) "82",
 18         max(case when udn_id =  64 then txt_Value end) "64",
 19         max(case when udn_id =  89 then txt_value end) "89",
 20         max(case when udn_id = 178 then txt_Value end) "178"
 21  from tbl
 22  group by prj_id;

    PRJ_ID 82         64         89         178
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      8335 05/10/2009 E S        N          End
      8344 13/10/2009 E S                   End
      8364 12/10/2009 A M        M          Internal

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Oracle syntaxes. So, I have written in SQL server syntax. Hope this helps you:

```
CREATE TABLE Project(PRJ_ID int, UDN_ID INT, TXT_VALUE varchar(100));

INSERT INTO Project VALUES (8344,82,'E S'),(8344,69,'A M'),(8364,82,'End'),(8364,59,'Internal');

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @columns1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

--selecting distinct values and concatenating to get a result like [82],[69],[82]...


SELECT @columns1 = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + '['+ CAST(UDN_ID AS VARCHAR) + ']' FROM Project
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
FROM Project;


--using that dynamic column string in the pivot query string


SET @sql = 'SELECT PRJ_ID,' + @columns1 + ' FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM Project
) AS src
PIVOT
(
  MAX(TXT_VALUE) FOR src.UDN_ID IN ('+ @columns1
  + ')
) AS p;';


--executing the pivot query


EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: This is not an appropriate answer for Oracle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. will change the syntax now.

Comment: I tried my best to change the syntax to Oracle. But, it was very exhaustive. will improve it later Gordon. Anyway, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable using the PIVOT in oracle.
Please use below and let me know in case of any queries.

```
select * from (
with all_data as(
select '8344' prj_id, 82 id, '40099' txt_val from dual union all
select '8344' prj_id, 64 id, 'E S' txt_val from dual union all
select '8344' prj_id, 178 id, 'End' txt_val from dual union all
select '8364' prj_id, 82 id, '40098' txt_val from dual union all
select '8364' prj_id, 64 id, 'A M' txt_val from dual union all
select '8364' prj_id, 89 id, 'M' txt_val from dual union all
select '8364' prj_id, 178 id, 'Internal' txt_val from dual union all
select '8335' prj_id, 82 id, '40091' txt_val from dual union all
select '8335' prj_id, 64 id, 'E S' txt_val from dual union all
select '8335' prj_id, 89 id, 'N' txt_val from dual union all
select '8335' prj_id, 178 id, 'End' txt_val from dual union all
select '8377' prj_id, 82 id, '40099' txt_val from dual union all
select '8377' prj_id, 64 id, 'Z D' txt_val from dual union all
select '8377' prj_id, 89 id, 'N;M' txt_val from dual union all
select '8377' prj_id, 178 id, 'Internal' txt_val from dual)
select prj_id,id,txt_val from all_data)
pivot
(max(txt_val) 
for id in (82 as "82_val", 64 as "64_val", 89 as "89_val", 178 as "178_val"))
order by 1
;
```

Comment: I've got more than 3million lines, so this is not a reasonable method. :-(

Comment: So, the values in the **for** needs to done as dynamic sql. the corrected syntax by the first answer by shabari should work for you.